# SQL - Unique Column 5 random digits

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am fairly new to SQL and I am looking to have a column that will generate 5 unique digits. Much like an id column, except I am looking to get 5 digits that are in random order and be unique for that column

Example:

```
56829
73591
17469
46290
```

I do have an id column that is auto increment and unique, but now I need another column that is unique and will generate 5 digits, I have kinda looked into this and apparently there is a uniqueidentifier column type and I have documentation on it, but I am not sure if its what I am looking for....Please help!

Comment: How many rows do you have?  Five digits only takes you to a hundred thousand rows.

Comment: There will be no more than 6000 rows

Comment: Basically what I am looking for is for this to be generate on insert, just like auto_increment unique id column

Comment: Would you be against using a GUID as the unique identifier? It's 32 characters and random, as far as I know.

Comment: This is not a good thing to do. You will be forced to use a loop to ensure that any new number has not already been used. If anything you should create a table of "random" numbers and then just use the first one that isn't already being used. This type of thing is almost always fraught with issues because somebody is putting too much value on a nonsense number.

Comment: @justiceorjustus I would be okay with that, how do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps a pseudo-random number would be enough.  You could do something like:

```
alter table t
    add id5 as ( (id * 19379 + 62327) % 99991)
```

The numbers are just arbitrary prime numbers less than 100,000.  Because they are primes, the numbers should not repeat for the values between 1 and 99991.

EDIT:

This is fairly easy to prove for prime numbers.  Assume that id1 and id2 have the same value:

```
(id1 * 19379 + 62327) % 99991) = n
(id2 * 19379 + 62327) % 99991) = n
```

Then subtract them:

```
(id1 - id2) * 19379 % 99991 = 0
```

Admittedly, you need a bit of Number Theory at this point.  But, suffice it to say that two primes (19,379 and 99,991) have no divisors in common.  So, the only way this can be true is when `id1 - id2` is a multiple of 99,991.

(Technically, what you can do is divide by 19,379 because its inverse is well-defined.  Inverses are not always well-defined in modulo arithmetic, but when they are division is allowed.)

That latter condition is a fancy way of saying that the numbers do not repeat.

EDIT:

If you want 5 digits, then you can use `% 89989` and add 10,000 to the result.

Comment: creative - have you ever needed something like this in the past?

Comment: Very interesting! I feel like I'm not mathy enough for this, so I may run a simulation out of curiosity and see the duplicates...

Comment: Yup, not one duplicate for possible Id's 0-99991.

Comment: This is a pretty slick solution for the originally posted requirements.

Comment: There are days that I feel pretty good about my abilities... then I see something like this... reality sucks.

Comment: This works perfectly, however why do I get a minus before my number? `-23569`

Comment: @GordonLinoff is it possible to do this without the minus?

Comment: @user979331 . . . Yes.  In fact, I usually use `+` and I'm not sure why I used `-` originally.

Comment: Ahhhh I found an issue, yes there are no duplicates, however sometimes I only get 4 digits `id * 19379 + 62327) % 99991`

Comment: @GordonLinoff question.....if I change id * 19379 + 62327) % 99991 to id * 19379 + 62327) % 89989 it will give me 5 digits and not 4

Comment: @GordonLinoff nope I still get 4 digits sometimes.

Comment: @user979331 . . . And add 10,000 to the result.

Comment: Just add + 10000 after % 89989?

Answer (score 1):

I've never really used UNIQUEIDENTIFIER in this way, so I may get corrected. This way you should be able to create a unique GUID as the auto-generating unique Id for the row.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,UniqueId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID()
    ,...Other columns
);
```

Comment: I created the table to test like so `CREATE TABLE TestingTable (
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,UniqueId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
 Name Varchar(MAX)
);` and tried to insert into this test table `INSERT INTO TestingTable VALUES ('James')` and got this error Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: newsequentialid is rather useless. They are predictable and not random in the least.

Comment: This isn't exactly 5 digits.

Comment: but that isn't what your post says, @user979331.... *Unique Column 5 random digits*

Comment: Yes it does, but if its more than 5 im cool with that too. 5 digits would be ideal

Comment: @user97931 your insert syntax was wrong, you need to specify the column where you're putting the data.  INSERT INTO TestingTable(Name) VALUES ('James').

Comment: I only posted this due to the user's comments stating that a GUID would be fine, as it is the usual solution to cases like this. @GordonLinoff has the exact answer for the given parameters in the question. May I get down from this cross now?